# Should a really bad answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, wrong-answers

When reviewing "low quality" postings I was pointed to the single answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132554/will-a-compiled-program-run-in-all-computers). The answer has already 6 downvotes; and is wrong to the bone.

But it is an answer. And I got ban-educated-conditioned to **not** delete answer attempts. "You downvote them, but you do not delete them.".

Even this one?

Comment: [relevant MSO link](/questions/287603/why-are-we-supposed-to-let-incorrect-answers-stick-around)

Comment: In the case you linked, the [question's going to get vacuumed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/159251) anyways; it'll just take the answer with it.

Comment: Why are you asking a question that you already know the answer to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even this one?

Yes, even this one.  Quoting the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

> You may vote to delete answers in the following cases:
>
> - The answer is extremely low quality: There is little to no scope for improvement
> - The answer doesn't attempt to answer the question; it may be a comment or a separate question altogether.

This answer does not fall into either of those categories so it does not qualify for manual deletion.  It's been down voted to oblivion and that should be enough of a signal to anyone that it is bad advice/completely wrong.

Comment: That I like. And a good quote behind it.

Answer (score -9):

> The answer has already 6 downvotes; and is **wrong to the bone**... But it is an answer.

Then ignore the rules and vote to delete the "answer".

When a rule prevents you from getting rid of crap, you should break it and the powers that be should allow you to do so.

Comment: So since this answer is objectively wrong we should just delete it here, right?

Comment: We *have* rules for a reason. Sometimes it's valid to ignore them, but this is not the case. Voting is the intended mechanism to judge the correctness of an answer; using other mechanisms like deletion breaks things.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Hmm. What *things* does deletion break?

Comment: @DavidPostill The system :P